# Subsetting within a function

Tags: r

I'm trying to subset a dataframe within a function using a mixture of fixed variables and some  variables which are created within the function (I only know the variable names, but cannot vectorise them beforehand). Here is a simplified example:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4)
b<-c(2,2,3,5)
c<-c(1,1,2,2)
D<-data.frame(a,b,c)

subbing<-function(Data,GroupVar,condition){
  g=Data$c+3
  h=Data$c+1
  NewD<-data.frame(a,b,g,h)
  subset(NewD,select=c(a,b,GroupVar),GroupVar%in%condition)
}
```

Keep in mind that in my application I cannot compute g and h outside of the function. Sometimes I'll want to make a selection according to the values of h (as above) and other times I'll want to use g. There's also the possibility I may want to use both, but even just being able to subset using 1 would be great.

```
subbing(D,GroupVar=h,condition=5)
```

This returns an error saying that the object h cannot be found. I've tried to amend subset using as.formula and all sorts of things but I've failed every single time.

Besides the ease of the function there is a further reason why I'd like to use subset.

In the function I'm actually working on I use subset twice. The first time it's the simple subset function. It's just been pointed out below that another blog explored how it's probably best to use the good old data[colnames()=="g",]. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a go.

There is however another issue. I also use subset (or rather a variation) in my function because I'm dealing with several complex design surveys (see package survey), so subset.survey.design allows you to get the right variance estimation for subgroups. If I selected my group using [] I would get the wrong s.e. for my parameters, so I guess this is quite an important issue.

Thank you

Comment: You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9860090/324364) question (it could possibly be considered a duplicate, though it's kind of a stretch).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's happening right as the function is trying to define `GroupVar` in the beginning. R is looking for the object `h` by itself (not within the dataframe).

The best thing to do is refer to the column names in quotes in the `subset` function. But of course, then you'd have to sidestep the condition part:

```
subbing <- function(Data, GroupVar, condition) {
   ....
   DF <- subset(Data, select=c("a","b", GroupVar))
   DF <- DF[DF[,3] %in% condition,]
}
```

That will do the trick, although it can be annoying to have one data frame indexing inside another.

Comment: For safety, I would probably also ditch `subset` entirely and move the `select` piece into the final line as well. (And I was about to ask the OP why they create `NewD` but then return a subset of `Data`; typo, perhaps...)

Comment: @joran - That's another good way to do it. You can just have `DF <- DF[DF[,GroupVar %in% condition],c("a","b",GroupVar)]`. I tend to prefer subset since it has its own environment, but in these cases the bracket notation minimizes the potential for error. As a side note, using `with(DF, DF[...])` eliminates the need for the cumbersome `$` operator, which is sometimes a good option.